# Python Selenium doesn't work in wordpress admin page

Tags: python, selenium

selenium doesn't work in my wordpress admin panel(can't select option as image2). Please help me! I'm beginner of programing.

[image1 : Wordpress Admin Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj747.jpg)

[image2 : After CSV File Uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so5Ym.jpg)

python: 3.6
Selenium: newest

```
# coding: utf-8   
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# WordPress admin page ( image1 )
browser.get(wai1url)
sleep(5)

# upload csv file
browser.find_element_by_link_text(u"ファイルをアップロードする").click()
sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite('link_20')
sleep(3)
pyautogui.press('down')
sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('return')
sleep(2)

#
# after csv file uploaded ( image2 )
#

# page scroll
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

# below code worked
browser.find_element_by_link_text(u"既存の項目").click()
sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_link_text(u"新規の項目").click()
sleep(3)

# But below code doesn't work
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('custom_type_selector'))

for index in range(len(select.options)):
    select = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('custom_type_selector'))
    select.select_by_index(4) # select Users
```

HTML of problem part is below.

```
<select name="custom_type_selector" id="custom_type_selector" class="wpallimport-post-types">

<option value="post" data-imagesrc="dashicon dashicon-post" selected="selected">投稿</option>

<option value="page" data-imagesrc="dashicon dashicon-page" >固定ページ</option>

<option value="taxonomies" data-imagesrc="dashicon dashicon-taxonomies" >Taxonomies</option>

<option value="import_users" data-imagesrc="dashicon dashicon-import_users" >Users</option>

</select>
```

I tried some methods. For example...

```
s1 = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('custom_type_selector'))
s1.select_by_index(4)
```

result >>> selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on 　＜select＞ elements, not on ＜div＞

and next,

```
s1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='wpallimport-choose-import-direction']/select/option[@value='post']")

s1.click()
```

result >>> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

and next,

```
s1 = browser.find_element_by_id('custom_type_selector')
for option in s1.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Users':
        option.click()
        sleep(60)
        break
```

either not work. Why?

How Should I code?

Comment: Check if another element, with  `<div>` tag, has name/id `custom_type_selector`

Comment: thank you,Guy. I checked ＜div＞tags. but they has no name/id custom_type_selector.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to select an option from dropdown?
This would help.

```
 browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='custom_type_selector']/option[text()='Users']").click()
```

Comment: thank you for your help. but,above code didn't work.

>>> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@name='custom_type_selector']/option[text()='Users']"}

Comment: add sleep(5) before it?

Comment: try  just this 
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='custom_type_selector']).click()